# Unable to read files by using akka stream

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor, akka-stream

We are trying to read files from akka streams. Files contains logs and the application is simple for write the logs into new files. But when, run our program, we are getting unexpected output. Our code is a below:

```
class LogsAkkaStream {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("AkkaStreams")
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/home/harmeet/workspace/mylogs.logs"))
  val sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("."), Set(CREATE, WRITE, APPEND))
  val runnableGraph: RunnableGraph[Future[IOResult]] = source.to(sink)

  runnableGraph.run().foreach { result =>
    println(s"${result.status}, ${result.count} bytes read. ")
  }
}

object LogsAkkaStream extends App {
  new LogsAkkaStream
}
```

`mylogs.logs` contains 1000 line record, but `output` of this program is : `Success(Done), 0 bytes read.` Still, we are not getting the actual program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I put in known-working paths to files then it works in my REPL.

You'll want to make sure the path to your source file is correct, and you'll want to put a correct destination path to a *file*.

Also, you'll want to use `toMat` instead of `to` so that you can get both the IOResult of the Read operations as well as the Write operations. (I'd recommend doing `_ zip _` so you get a `Future[(IOResult, IOResult)]`).

Comment: Hey @Viktor file is on correct path, but I am not sure, what will happen ?

Comment: @harmeet-singh-taara check your destination path - "." is no good, please use a filename instead.

Comment: @Viktor, we are change our code like `FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("home/harmeet/logs.log"), Set(CREATE, WRITE, APPEND))`, but still same output occur.

Comment: You'll need to verify your source and destination paths. "home/harmeet/logs.log" is relative.

Make sure you use the canonical path.

Comment: Thanks @ViktorKlang this is working, That means `current-directory(.)` path doesn.t work in `Paths.get(".")` .